# Why does my backbone.Collection have only one element? (using Require, TypeScript, Jasmine)

Tags: javascript, typescript, backbone.js, requirejs

*I'm new to TypeScript and Jasmine, and still fairly new to Backbone and Require so I'm still trying to glue some pieces together.*

In a Jasmine test in a TypeScript file, I am trying to define a `backbone.Collection`. Here is my code (stilghtly refactored)

```
(...)

class ModelA extends backbone.Model {
    idAttribute: "N";
    constructor(N: number, StringPropertyA: string, StringPropertyB: string, NumericPropertyA: number, NumericPropertyB: number, DatePropertyA: Date, DatePropertyB : Date) {
        super();
        this.attributes.N = N;
        this.attributes.StringPropertyA = StringPropertyA;
        this.attributes.StringPropertyB = StringPropertyB;
        this.attributes.NumericPropertyA = NumericPropertyA;
        this.attributes.NumericPropertyB = NumericPropertyB;
        this.attributes.DatePropertyA = DatePropertyA;
        this.attributes.DatePropertyB = DatePropertyB;
    }
}
            //var OldModelA = backbone.Model.extend({
            //    idAttribute: "N",
            //    constructor: function (N, PropertyA, PropertyB) {
            //        this.N = N;
            //        this.PropertyA = PropertyA;
            //        this.PropertyB = PropertyB;
            //    }
            //});

            var ModelACollection = backbone.Collection.extend({model: ModelA});

            var i = 1;
            var model1 = new ModelA(i++, "Abc", "dfD9"),
                model2 = new ModelA(i++, "Cde", "gdkl"),
                model3 = new ModelA(i++, "Cdy", "grger"),
                model4 = new ModelA(i++, "Zly", "dzeersds"),
                model5 = new ModelA(i++, "Zlz", "sdfsfz");

            var modelArray = [model1, model2, model3, model4, model5];

            var collection1 = new ModelACollection({ models: modelArray });
            var collection2 = new backbone.Collection({ models: modelArray });

(...)
```

I expected `collection1.models` and `collection2.models` to be arrays of 5 elements, but here are their content according to Chrome:

I guess I'm missing something...

[image: Content of collection1 and collection2 according to Chrome's debugger]

**Further searching**
Similar result with

```
        var collection3 = new backbone.Collection();
        collection3.add(model1);
        collection3.add(model2);
        collection3.add(model3);
        collection3.add(model4);
        collection3.add(model5);
```

Comment: You're not using Backbone models correctly.

Comment: Thank you. So what would be the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model definition is the culprit, it hopelessly confuses Backbone:

- it misses a call to the parent constructor to inherit `Backbone.Model` properties. See the second example in http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor
- if you want to write the attributes directly, they must be stored in the `attributes` hash, for example

  ```
  this.attributes.N = N;
  this.attributes.PropertyA = PropertyA;
  this.attributes.PropertyB = PropertyB;
  ```

Given those points, a possible definition for `ModelA`, calling the parent constructor with a hash of attributes :

```
var ModelA = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "N",
    constructor: function (N, PropertyA, PropertyB) {
        Backbone.Model.call(this, {
            N: N,
            PropertyA: PropertyA,
            PropertyB: PropertyB
        });
    }
});

var m = new ModelA(1, "Abc", "dfD9");
console.log(m.toJSON());
```

Note that you would create your collection with the array of models as first argument if you haven't overridden the constructor:

```
var collection1 = new ModelACollection(modelArray);
```

And a demo

```js
var ModelA = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "N",
    constructor: function (N, PropertyA, PropertyB) {
        Backbone.Model.call(this, {
            N: N,
            PropertyA: PropertyA,
            PropertyB: PropertyB
        });
    }
});

var i = 1;
var model1 = new ModelA(i++, "Abc", "dfD9"),
    model2 = new ModelA(i++, "Cde", "gdkl"),
    model3 = new ModelA(i++, "Cdy", "grger"),
    model4 = new ModelA(i++, "Zly", "dzeersds"),
    model5 = new ModelA(i++, "Zlz", "sdfsfz");
var collection1 = new Backbone.Collection([model1, model2, model3, model4, model5]);
console.log(collection1.toJSON());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I suspected something wrong with the idAttribute. Probably it's because they're all similar that only one item gets added. However, I need to define my model with TypeScript, and between the time I posted and the time this question was answered, I changed my model to TypeScript. I edited the original post with the current definition of the model, which is partly based on this answer, but still not working.

Comment: You're still creating your collection with a hash `new ModelACollection({ models: modelArray });` instead of an array of models `new ModelACollection(modelArray);` but please don't change your question as it invalidates the main point of my answer.

Comment: Solved with this comment. I agree it was a bit messy I had to edit the original post, but when I posted the question, no answers came for hours and I had to go forward in my work, hence I didn't the same code as when I posted the question in order to test anything.